# How to send email in zend using Amazon SES?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, zend-framework, amazon-ses

I am new to zend framework (v1.8) and I am trying to send email to user using Amazon SES. It look like I have to select template and passing throgh dynamic data into a function. 
I have tried a Transport : https://github.com/christophervalles/Amazon-SES-Zend-Mail-Transport
But it does not fulfill my requirement. It do not support to using templates or dynamic data.
Can anyone help me out of this?

plox : bad english

Answer (score 0):

I am done with my requirement. I replaced default Zend mail code to Amazon SES code.